# How to debug dll (Unity)?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a Unity project that use dll.

This is an example I try to use : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C6V1f86x058

In order to make it work I :

1. created C# script
2. Added dll under Assets folder

My script is

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Rendering;

public class TestScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    //the name of the DLL you want to load stuff from
    private const string pluginName = "AndroidNativeLib";
    //native interface
    [DllImport(pluginName)]
    private static extern IntPtr getEventFunction();

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public delegate void DebugDelegate(string str);

    static void CallBackFunction(string str) { Debug.Log(str); }

    [DllImport(pluginName)]
    public static extern void SetDebugFunction(IntPtr fp);


    private CommandBuffer cmd;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        DebugDelegate callback_delegate = new DebugDelegate(CallBackFunction);
        // Convert callback_delegate into a function pointer that can be
        // used in unmanaged code.
        IntPtr intptr_delegate =
            Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(callback_delegate);
        // Call the API passing along the function pointer.
        SetDebugFunction(intptr_delegate);

        //crating the command buffer and attaching it to camera
        cmd = new CommandBuffer();
        cmd.name = pluginName;
        var camera = Camera.main;
        camera.AddCommandBuffer(CameraEvent.AfterGBuffer, cmd);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        cmd.IssuePluginEvent(getEventFunction(), 0);
    }
}
```

And my dll is :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "IUnityGraphics.h"

//make sure this appears before IUnityGraphicsD3D11
#include "d3d11.h"

#include "IUnityGraphicsD3D11.h"


// debug event
typedef void(*FuncPtr)(const char *);
FuncPtr Debug;

namespace globals {
    ID3D11Device *device = nullptr;
    ID3D11DeviceContext *context = nullptr;
} // namespace globals

extern "C" {

    UNITY_INTERFACE_EXPORT void SetDebugFunction(FuncPtr fp) { Debug = fp; }

    // Plugin function to handle a specific rendering event
    static void UNITY_INTERFACE_API  UNITY_INTERFACE_API OnRenderEvent(int eventID) {
        Debug("Hello world");
    }


    // Unity plugin load event
    void UNITY_INTERFACE_EXPORT UNITY_INTERFACE_API
        UnityPluginLoad(IUnityInterfaces *unityInterfaces) {
        auto s_UnityInterfaces = unityInterfaces;
        IUnityGraphicsD3D11 *d3d11 = unityInterfaces->Get<IUnityGraphicsD3D11>();
        globals::device = d3d11->GetDevice();
        globals::device->GetImmediateContext(&globals::context);
    }

    // Unity plugin unload event
    void UNITY_INTERFACE_EXPORT UNITY_INTERFACE_API UnityPluginUnload() {}

    // Freely defined function to pass a callback to plugin-specific scripts
    UnityRenderingEvent UNITY_INTERFACE_EXPORT UNITY_INTERFACE_API
        getEventFunction() {
        return OnRenderEvent;
    }
}
```

When I run this example I don't see any outputs and it does not looks like it work. So, I tried to debug it. I can get debug point in C# script, but if I try to reach one from dll code, noting happens.

So, question is - how to debug dll code?

Answer (score -1):

Does this help: https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-build-and-debug-external-dlls.161685/

> 1. create a .csproj file that uses wildcards to find all source code
> 2. add this C# project to a Visual Studio solution
> 3. use an MSBuild post-build target to convert Visual Studio's PDB symbols to Mono's MDB format
> 4. debug with MonoDevelop from Unity, as normal
> 5. source code should -not- be in the Assets folder, but the generated DLL should be

Comment: Not sure why you're "answering" a question with a question, this should be a comment instead. Furthermore, that thread is now nearly a decade old (the unity engine has changed significantly over the years) and is very specific to VS.

Did you simply google the issue and copy-paste the first link you found or what?

Comment: I can't understand your point at all. I'm not asking a question, I'm just polite with a Does this help and then provide a comment that is to remain on this platform with a solution that worked for me and might not exist on the url in the future. I'm strongly missing your point here. The question remains a 10 year old question. Ask for the question to be deleted if you don't find it relevant, don't try to be smart.